# How to downgrade easyocr versions using pip?

Tags: pip, anaconda, easyocr

I currently have easyocr 1.7.0 but I need to downgrade to 1.6.2, how can I force pip to install this version of easyocr?

I tried to uninstall my current version of easyocr but I don't know how to, and if I install easyocr again, it will install the latest version but I specifically need version 1.6.2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+install+specific+package+version

Comment: `pip install easyocr==1.6.2`